# javascript asynchonously update a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show multiple images in a DIV in a web page one after another. There should be a time gap between two images. Here is the code I tried for that.

```
$('#abc').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="D:/Image_Store/Character/Animal/Pet/cat2.png" />')
    wait(1000);
    $('#abc').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="D:/Image_Store/Character/Animal/Pet/dog1.png" />')
    wait(1000);
    $('#abc').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="D:/Image_Store/Character/Animal/Pet/dog2.png" />')
    wait(1000);
    $('#abc').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="D:/Image_Store/Character/Animal/Pet/parrot1.png" />')
    wait(1000);
```

**EDIT**

wait function is here

```
function wait(ms){
       var start = new Date().getTime();
       var end = start;
       while(end < start + ms) {
         end = new Date().getTime();
      }
    }
```

But this is not working and only show the last image. How can I figure out that?

Comment: pease provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you come up with the `wait` function?

Comment: i added that function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't suspend execution of JavaScript code between lines in a browser. (Not in a useful way; `alert` and such sort of do.) Or at least, if you do, the entire UI of the browser (or at least that tab) locks up and no page updates are rendered.

Instead, schedule a series of timed callbacks to update your image:

```
[   "D:/Image_Store/Character/Animal/Pet/cat2.png",
    "D:/Image_Store/Character/Animal/Pet/dog1.png",
    "D:/Image_Store/Character/Animal/Pet/dog2.png",
    "D:/Image_Store/Character/Animal/Pet/parrot1.png"
].forEach(function(img, index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("<img>").attr("src", img).prependTo("#abc");
    }, 1000 * index);
});
```

There we schedule the first update after 0ms, the second after 1000ms, the third after 2000ms, etc.

---

Side note: Your original code was adding **multiple** `img` elements with the same `id` value. The code above still uses multiple `img` elements, but doesn't give them an `id`, since using the same `id` on more than one element is invalid.

If your goal was to have a **single** `img` element that you updated with multiple sources, we'd do that slightly differently:

```
[   "D:/Image_Store/Character/Animal/Pet/cat2.png",
    "D:/Image_Store/Character/Animal/Pet/dog1.png",
    "D:/Image_Store/Character/Animal/Pet/dog2.png",
    "D:/Image_Store/Character/Animal/Pet/parrot1.png"
].forEach(function(img, index) {
    if (index === 0) {
        // Create and append the img
        $("<img>").attr("id", "theImg").attr("src", img).prependTo("#abc");
    } else {
        // Update it
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#theImg").attr("src", img);
        }, 1000 * index);
    }
});
```